# Desoldering speaker cable in order to replace with fresh and longer wire

Tags: soldering

I have the following speaker crack oppened and showing its guts:

[image: My speaker's guts]

What I want to do it is to place a fresh wires for audio IO becasuse in these wires exist a 3.5mm audio jack as audio IO.

My problem is on how I can desolder the Audio ΙΟ wire without desoldering the rest of the wiring. For desoldering I will use desoldering braid. (Seemed easier for me instead of solder sucker.)

Also the soldering wire will also be 0.3mm with flux.

Comment: Why desolder? Why not just cut that back to say ... 30cm and splice on to the copper harness

Comment: So you are sayng just place the old wire into the new one, right?

Comment: Don't bother with desolder braid, just heat it up and pull the old wires off.  The others may come off as well, in which case you simply put them back when you solder the new ones.  Just be careful not to loose or break the enameled wire that comes out of the coil itself to some part of those terminals.

Comment: @Sorenp I think that is good enough to be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you aren't comfortable soldering all the wires off, I would suggest you cut the wires leaving about ~5 cm. strip the insulation, clean the wire with alcohol covered swaps, let it dry then "braid" the new wire around the old and solder it together, then cover the splice with some heat shrink tube.

There are many guides out there as how to best splice multi core cables.